# RavenDB TransformResult: Assign properties of a document to each elements of a collection

Tags: ravendb, transformation

I want to transform some RavenDB Documents to a view model which is more suitable for the UI. The ContractorModel Object should look as follows:

```
public class ContractorModel
{
   public string Identifier {get; set;}
   public TrustcenterModel[] {get; set; }
}

public class TrustcenterModel
{
   public string Ean {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The corresponding json docs are in the following format:

```
ContractorJson:
{
  "Identifier": "42",
  "Trustcenters": [
    {
      "Ean": "2222222222222",
      "ValidFrom": "2016-01-13T00:00:00.0000000",
      "ValidTo": "2499-12-31T00:00:00.0000000"
    }
  ]
}
TrustcenterJson:
{
  "Ean": "2222222222222",
  "Name": "FooBar",
}
```

When I query a Contractor with the subsequent Transformer, I already get the related Trustcenter documents, but I'm missing the two properties ValidFrom and ValidTo. How can I project these two properties from the contractor to each trustcenter?

```
this.TransformResults = contractors =>
                from contractor in contractors
                select new
                {
                    contractor.Identifier,
                    Trustcenters = contractor.Trustcenters.Select(x =>  this.LoadDocument<TrustCenter>(TrustCenter.IdPrefix + x.Ean)),
                };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
this.TransformResults = contractors =>
                from contractor in contractors
                select new
                {
                    contractor.Identifier,
                    Trustcenters = contractor.Trustcenters.Select(x => new
                    {
                        x.Ean,
                        x.ValidFrom,
                        x.ValidTo,
                        Name = this.LoadDocument<TrustCenter>(TrustCenter.IdPrefix + x.Ean).Name
                    }),
                };
```